# AutoLisp Get Last Modified

Tags: lisp, autolisp

I'm trying to get the last modified date from a list of files for a sort option. I have found a source, [here](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/visual-lisp-autolisp-and-general/change-file-date-with-lisp/m-p/10825973/highlight/true#M425019), where someone can update when a file was last modified, but I'm having trouble reversing the process. I keep receiving `Error: Missing parameter for function.` message when I try to use `vlax-get` and `vlax-get-property`.

```lisp
(vl-load-com)

;; Original code
(defun SetFileLastModified ( file date / i fso fObj sh 
    oFolder oFiles iCount fItem filepath
    vTemp) 
      
    (setq fso (vlax-create-object "Scripting.FileSystemObject"))
    (if (= (vlax-invoke fso 'FileExists file) :vlax-true)
        (progn ;; True
            (setq sh (vla-getinterfaceobject (vlax-get-acad-object) "Shell.Application"))
            (setq oFolder (vlax-invoke sh 'NameSpace (vl-filename-directory file)))
            (setq oFiles (vlax-invoke oFolder 'Items))
            (setq iCount (vlax-get oFiles 'Count))
            (setq i 0)
            (while (< i iCount)
                (setq fItem (vlax-invoke oFiles 'Item i))
                (setq filepath (vlax-get fItem 'path))
                (if (= (vl-filename-base filepath) (vl-filename-base file))(progn
                    (vlax-put fItem 'ModifyDate date);<-- Command to update the last modified date.
                ));if
                (setq i (1+ i))
            );while
            (vlax-release-object sh)
        );progn ; True
        (print (strcat "File not found: " file)); False
    );if
    (vlax-release-object fso)
);PullLastModified


;; Failed attempt
(defun PullLastModified ( file / i fso fObj sh 
    oFolder oFiles iCount fItem filepath
    vTemp) 
     
    (setq fso (vlax-create-object "Scripting.FileSystemObject"))
    (if (= (vlax-invoke fso 'FileExists file) :vlax-true)
        (progn ;; True
            (setq sh (vla-getinterfaceobject (vlax-get-acad-object) "Shell.Application"))
            (setq oFolder (vlax-invoke sh 'NameSpace (vl-filename-directory file)))
            (setq oFiles (vlax-invoke oFolder 'Items))
            (setq iCount (vlax-get oFiles 'Count))
            (setq i 0)
            (while (< i iCount)
                (setq fItem (vlax-invoke oFiles 'Item i))
                (setq filepath (vlax-get fItem 'path))
                (if (= (vl-filename-base filepath) (vl-filename-base file))(progn
                    (princ "\nTest-01\n")
                    (setq vTemp (vlax-get fItem 'ModifyDate));<-- Having trouble pulling the modified date.
                    (princ "\nModified Date : ")(prin1 vTemp)(terpri)
                ));if
                (setq i (1+ i))
            );while
            (vlax-release-object sh)
        );progn ; True
        (print (strcat "File not found: " file)); False
    )
    (vlax-release-object fso)
);PullLastModified
```

**Update**

Found the reason why I cannot use `'DateLastModified` to pull the latest modification date. Alternatives?

[image: Data Property Values]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code appears to be performing many unnecessary operations when obtaining the file object: rather than using the [`Namespace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-namespace) property of the [Shell object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell) to obtain the folder and then iterating over the contents of the folder until arriving at a file with the target filename, you can obtain the file object directly using the [`getfile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/getfile-method) method of the [File System Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/filesystemobject-object) (FSO).

Consider the following code:

```lisp
(defun LM:filelastmodified ( fnm / fob fso rtn )
    (cond
        (   (not (setq fnm (findfile fnm))))
        (   (setq fso (vlax-get-or-create-object "scripting.filesystemobject"))
            (setq fob (vlax-invoke-method fso 'getfile fnm)
                  rtn (+ 2415019 (vlax-get fob 'datelastmodified))
            )
            (vlax-release-object fob)
            (vlax-release-object fso)
        )
    )
    rtn
)
```

The above function will return a [Julian datetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) representing the last modified date of the file - you can then use the `edtime` [DIESEL](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-F94A885A-4DA2-432B-AC1A-EB49CC6C1C72) function within a `menucmd` expression to output this as a readable datetime, e.g.:

```lisp
(defun c:test ( / fnm mod )
    (cond
        (   (not (setq fnm (getfiled "Select File" "" "" 16)))
            (princ "\n*Cancel*")
        )
        (   (not (setq mod (LM:filelastmodified fnm)))
            (princ "\nUnable to obtain last modified date.")
        )
        (   (princ (strcat "\nLast modified: " (menucmd (strcat "m=$(edtime," (rtos mod 2 15) ",yyyy-mo-dd hh:mm:ss)")))))
    )
    (princ)
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the recommended improvements. This solution looks like it should work. Unfortunately, I'm receiving this error: `Error: Invalid parameter.` . I suspect that I'll need to ask the developers about this issue.

Comment: @GBeck The code works for me; what platform are you running this on, and what expression is erroring? (you can find this by following [this](http://lee-mac.com/debugvlide.html#where) tutorial).

Comment: The platform I'm using is DraftSight. The function that is throwing me the error is `(vlax-get fob 'datelastmodified)` .

Comment: Also, when I add the code with `(prin1 (vla-get-name fob))`  before the error point, file's name is returned to the command line.

Comment: I've raised a ticket within the DraftSight community. The source of this issue is within DraftSight. Once this issue is resolved, the solution you've written should work for me. Thank you.